# Using synchronized DEs in decision split in journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

We are using Salesforce data as the entry event in our journeys. As we have some latency between a record gets injected into the journey, till certain data attributes is updated, we have been using synchronized data extensions to monitor if these attributes gets set correctly. Our synched DE are updating every 15min and we have added a 20min wait period to allow the data to get updated.
We have however started noticing that some records gets ejected from the decision splits even though they are fulfilling the criteria in the decision split.
We are suspecting that the issue is related to the refresh of the synchronized DEs. When investigating this there doesn't seem to be an consistent answer to whether or not it is recommended to use synchronized data extensions.

Have anybody experience the same issues as we are facing? And is it related to the update of the DE's or is there something we are missing?

We are updating approx. 50K records on our synched DEs.

Comment: Are you using 1:1 or 1:many cardinality, when linking data extensions for decision splits in your Data Designer?  [There are some things you need to take care of](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_data_relationships.htm&type=5), when using decision splits, especially with 1:many relationships.

Comment: We are referencing the attribute group that is automatically created when synchronized data to Marketing Cloud, and here we have a 1:1 relationship between the Contact and Account (we are validating a field on Account)